# UIImageView in ScrollView aspect ratio not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, aspect-ratio

I have a UIScrollView defined in my storyboard, with an outlet. This scrollview gets a UIImageView added to it through code (not on storyboard). When I run the app, the image is stretched out of aspect. As soon as I touch to zoom the image, it snaps to its proper aspect ratio.

What is going on here?!

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageView = UIImageView()
var selectedImage: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    imageView.image = selectedImage
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true


    scrollView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()


    self.closeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(self.closeBtn.frame)/20.0


}
```

When loaded:
[image]

After moving zoom at all:
[image]

**ALMOST FIXED:**
I edited the code to define the imageView.frame in viewWillLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad, as was suggested in the answers below. I am now having a new issue - the image is unable to zoom in... it allows you to zoom until you release your fingers and then it snaps back to original size.

Is this to do with scrollView.maximumZoomScale not being big enough?

**corrected code:**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    //imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    imageView.image = selectedImage
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true


    scrollView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()


    self.closeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(self.closeBtn.frame)/20.0


}
```

Comment: can you please post a screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too early to set the frame in -viewDidLoad() method

if u will print your scrollView.frame in -viewDidLoad() this will actually return the frame before your view will layout it's subviews.

So u need to make constraints to imageView OR in viewWillLayout redefine imageView.frame.

Comment: Thanks so much - that fixed the loading in the wrong aspect. I now am unable to "stay" zoomed in though... any chance you can see the problem in the above updated edit? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try such trick in viewWillLayoutSubviews(): 

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width * scrollView.zoomScale, scrollView.frame.size.height * scrollView.zoomScale)

but It would be actually better to put constraints to your imageView rather than redefining its frame in -viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how it would work with constraints, but I don't want to bother you by asking for more help. I will read about adding constraints in code. If you feel extra motivated, any sort of example of applying the constraints properly would be helpful - I have always done them in storyboards and UIScrollviews seem to give me problems always.